# extract text between a[- and -] using python

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I am writing a script to extract data from a file and split the data to multiple files contents for each file is split by 5 "@"s

Example:

```
@@@@@

hello

@@@@@

world

@@@@@
```

in this case, "hello" should be in one file and "world" should be in another file

I am using python

Comment: show us the code you have now please

Comment: Which part of the program are you having problems with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you want to be able to take input from a file with a delimiter of @@@@@

```
@@@@@
hello
@@@@@
world
@@@@@
```

and this would generate a file for each block between

```
hello
```

and

```
world
```

You can use re.split to get the splits

```
splits = re.split("[@]{5}\n", input_buffer)
```

would give something like (note: above assumes the split also includes a newline)

```
['', 'hello\n', 'world\n', '']
```

and to get only the splits with actual text (assuming that trailing new lines are to be removed)

```
[i.strip() for i in splits if i]
```

Output filename was also not specified so used

```
for index, val in enumerate([i.strip() for i in splits if i]):
    with open("output%d"%index, "w+") as f:
```

to create files named output0, outputN

```
import re
import StringIO

input_text = '''@@@@@
hello
@@@@@
world
@@@@@
'''
string_file =  StringIO.StringIO(input_text)
input_buffer = string_file.read()

splits = re.split("[@]{5}\n", input_buffer)
for index, val in enumerate([i.strip() for i in splits if i]):
    with open("output%d"%index, "w+") as f:
        f.write(val)
```

Just a helper, can obviously use a different regular expression to split on, change output name to something more suitable, etc.

Also if as the title of this question says using text between [- and -] splits could be obtained using re.findall instead

```
input_text = '''[-hello-]
[-world-]
'''
string_file =  StringIO.StringIO(input_text)

input_buffer = string_file.read()
splits = re.findall("\[-(.*)-\]", input_buffer)
for index, val in enumerate(splits):
    with open("output%d"%index, "w+") as f:
        f.write(val)
```

Comment: Pretty sure `[@]{5}\n` wouldn't match the final '@@@@@'. Maybe better: `[@]{5}\n?` or just remove the newline altogether and let `strip()` do the work.

Comment: @brianpck is correct, I assumed newline terminated file,

Answer (score 1):

This could do the trick:

```
with open('a.txt') as r: #open source file and assign it to variable r
    r = r.read().split('@@@@@') #read the contents and break it into list of elements separated by '@@@@@'
    new = [item.strip() for item in r if item] #clean empty rows from the list

for i, item in enumerate(new): #iterate trough new list and assign a number to each iteration starting with 0 (default)
    with open('a%s.txt' % i+1, 'w') as w: #create new file for each element from the list that will be named 'a' + 'value of i + 1' + '.txt'
        w.write(item) #writing contents of current element into file
```

This will read your file that I called 'a.txt' and produce files named `a1.txt, a2.txt ... an.txt`

Comment: @nijeeshjoshy I added comment to each row. Hope it clears the picture.